# PHP array sort BY value, array_rand with condition

Tags: php

I have array

```
 $arr    =   [
    0   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  3,
        'name'      =>  'a3',
    ],
    2   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  3,
        'name'      =>  'b3',
    ],
    3   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  3,
        'name'      =>  'c3',
    ],
    4   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  1,
        'name'      =>  'a1',
    ],
    5   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  1,
        'name'      =>  'b1',
    ],
    6   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  5,
        'name'      =>  'a5',
    ],
    7   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  4,
        'name'      =>  'a4',
    ],
    8   =>  [
        'weight'    =>  3,
        'name'      =>  'd3',
    ],
];
```

Now i need sort array by 'weight' and i do:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {return $a['weight'] <=> $b['weight'];});
```

[image: OUTPUT IS:]

How i can sort array BY weight (as in the example above), and array_rand on duplicate weight?

[image]

Comment: Check if `$a['weight'] == $b['weight']`, and if so, return either -1 or 1 at random.

Comment: uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {return $a['weight'] == $b['weight'] ?   rand(-1,1)  :  $a['weight'] <=> $b['weight'];});
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {return $a['weight'] == $b['weight'] ?   rand(-1,1)  :  $a['weight'] <=> $b['weight'];});
```

Comment: Technically it is incorrect to return a random value from the callback. That function, for example, could claim that a < b and b < a at the same time. It works, yes.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes work;) What will be a right solution?

Comment: assign random weights (lets call it weight2) to each item in array before sorting. Then uasort function becomes `return $a['weight'] <=> $b['weight'] ?: $a['weight2'] <=> $b['weight2'];`. Of course this is not necessary, only grants inner peace.